# unable extends Interface Type Script :- Cannot find name "JQueryAjaxSettings"

Tags: typescript

I am new to typescript and trying to create a file for the very first time.
I have created one typescript file mytypescript.d.ts file I want to extend `JQueryAjaxSettings` I have added `jquery-3.3.1` to my project

```js
interface AjxCallInput<TContext = any> extends JQueryAjaxSettings 
{
    errorException?: errorException;
}
```

It is throwing build time error **Cannot find name "JQueryAjaxSettings"**

ps working on visual studio

Thank you all